# .NET 6 version of Request.GetClientCertificate() in a C#, ASP.NET Core MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-6.0

I'm upgrading from .NET Framework 4.8 to .NET 6 (I heard the groan from here....). Most things I can find analogies for, but I simply can't find a replacement for the MVC controller method `Request.GetClientCertificate()` in .NET 6.

Does anyone know of a replacement/analogy for this?

Answer (score 1):

```
builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(o => { 
    o.ConfigureHttpsDefaults(
        o => o.ClientCertificateMode = ClientCertificateMode.AllowCertificate
        );
});
```

```
var Certificate = Request.HttpContext.Connection.ClientCertificate;
var Certificate = await Request.HttpContext.Connection.GetClientCertificateAsync();
```